# node + robotjs очень долго выполняет действие

Tags: c#, node.js

Есть задача выполнять некие действия на сервере при получении GET или POST запроса... Вообщем это не столь важно... проблема в том что `robot.keyTap('audio_vol_up');` выполняется около 200ms. Это ооочень долго. сам запрос 5-8ms без выполнения функции keyTap.

У всех так медленно?
Можно ли заменить чем то быстым?
Готов написать свой модуль но на C# НО везде примеры запуска node как модуль C# а не наоборот.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/addons.html, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/n-api.html, https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/embedding.html

Comment: и https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues?q=keyTap+to+slow+is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed